# Linearly independent set $\{a,b,c\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to have a linearly independent set $\{a,b,c\}$ in the third dimension such that $\{a-b,b-a,a+c\}$ is linearly dependent? After many attempts, I cant seem to find an example to support this claim however, I don't understand why. Is there a better way of finding a solution to this problem than just "guessing and check"?

Answer (score 2):

Let $k_1(a+b) + k_2 (2b) + k_3(a-c)=0$ for some scalars $k_1,k_2,k_3$ from a field.

Then $(k_1+k_3)a + (2k_2)b + (-k_3)c=0$.

Since $a,b,c$ are linearly independent, the coefficients vanish: $k_1+k_3=0$, $2k_2=0$ and $-k_3=0$.

Thus $k_3=0$, $k_2=0$ and then also $k_1=0$.

Hence, $a+b, 2b, a-c$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ are linearly independent and $\left\{a+b,2b,a-c\right\}$ is linearly dependent. That implies that there exist three constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ (at least one of them non-zero) such that

$$
\alpha\left(a+b\right)+\beta\left(2b\right)+\gamma\left(a-c\right)=0
$$
Rearranging,
$$
a\left(\alpha+\gamma\right)+b\left(2\beta+\alpha\right)+c\left(-\alpha\right)=0
$$
But since $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ are linearly independent, we must have
$$
\alpha+\gamma=0\\
2\beta+\alpha=0\\
-\alpha=0
$$
From here we obtain $\alpha=0,\gamma=0,2\beta=0$. So assuming we are not working in over a field with characteristic $2$, the only solution to this is $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$. But this contradicts the assumption that at least one of them is non-zero. Hence we cannot assume that $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ is linearly independent and $\left\{a+b,2b,a-c\right\}$ is linearly dependent at the same times.

Hence we conclude that if $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ is linearly independent then so is $\left\{a+b,2b,a-c\right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the relation between a linearly independent set {a, b, c} in the third dimension where a combination of them is linearly dependent. But from what I remember from linear algebra, a vector space is any set V of vectors such that if x1, x2 are in V, then any linear combination rx1 + sx2 is also in V.

So basically, suppose we have a matrix

A =

```
1  1  4

1 -2  1
```

Let $a_c$ denote the cth column of A

Then this matrix can be re-written as

$a_3 = 3a_1 + a_2 $

Because

$ \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = 3 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$

This is basically saying that the first two columns of A are 
linearly independent however, the third column is linearly dependent on the first two columns.

I don't know if this helps but I hope it relates to your problem.